# List of most popular server side web hosting languages?

Tags: php, hosting, node.js, languages

I am looking for some online resources providing statistics, or at least ranking, of server-side installations based on the language (and maybe version and environment).

We are trying to choose the appropriate language for an upcoming general-purpose framework we are building, and a primary goal is to have  it installable by the most generic web hosting companies possible.

Obviously PHP is on top or close to it today. But what about Node.js or Rust? Can someone link to reliable sources that have conducted such a study recently?

Comment: If you want generic web hosting providers as your target, then PHP is likely your only option.

Answer (score 2):

W3Techs has [Usage of server-side programming languages for websites](https://w3techs.com/technologies/overview/programming_language/all) with reasonable [methodology](https://w3techs.com/technologies). Based on their survey, PHP currently has 83.5% market share, whereas server side JavaScript like Node.js only has 0,5%. Rust is not even listed.

ASP.NET and Java are the obvious competitors based on market share, but for "generic web hosting companies" PHP is probably the most rational choice for such a new platform.

As creating a whole platform doesn't happen in a day, I'd focus directly on PHP 7 despite the majority of current web sites [is running](https://w3techs.com/technologies/details/pl-php/all/all) on PHP 5. This is not about popularity but [support](http://php.net/supported-versions.php): active support for PHP 5.6 has ended 19 Jan 2017 and security support will end 31 Dec 2018.

Comment: Of course, it's not easy to reliably get this data in the first place, but I find a usage of 0.2% for Python very hard to believe ...

Comment: Aren't all sites WordPress nowadays? I think the market share per applications would be totally different. Also, the statistics are only based on public sites. Enough to explain this?